# Error when trying to invoke mergetool from git

Tags: git, mergetool, difftool, p4merge

Trying to invoke mergetool. Had previously set up both mergetool and difftool. Followed same process for both. Difftool works, but mergetool does not. When I try to invoke mergetool, I get:

```
SAR@DESKTOP-7MC10MV MINGW64 ~/projects/starter-web (master|MERGING)
$ git mergetool
Merging:
simple.html

Normal merge conflict for 'simple.html':
{local}: modified file
{remote}: modified file
The merge tool p4merge is not available as 'C:\Program Files\Perforce'
```

I have tried redoing the `~/.gitconfig`, but it just pops the same error as above.

```
   [diff]
        tool = p4merge
    [difftool "p4merge"]
        path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    [difftool]
        prompt = false
    [merge]
        tool = p4merge
    [mergetool "p4merge"]
        path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    [mergetool]
        prompt = false
```

Comment: Does `p4merge.exe` exist in `C:\Program Files\Perforce`?

Comment: yes, it does exist there